# Bootstrap - row in row that goes beyond it a bit

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background: #0d0d0d;
}

body a {
  color: #fff;
}

body a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    width: 1470px !important;
  }
}

nav {
  background: #1c1c1c !important;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.toper {
  padding: 100px;
  background: #071931;
  color: #fff;
}

.main {
  background: #121212;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.container-first {
  background: #2a2a2a;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.breadcrumb {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #2a2a2a;
}

.container-first-right {
  padding-top: 2px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-first-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
}

.welcome {
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.welcome-header {
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
}

.welcome-text {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.welcome-action {
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 20px;
  background: #4d4d4d;
  color: #ccc;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.bluer {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #046092;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.section-bluer {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.section-first {
  background: #1c1c1c;
}

.section-picture {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}

.section-picture>img {
  border: 1px solid #016d9b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container main">
    <div class="container-fluid bluer">
      <a href="#">Najnowszy news: #98 Tygodnik MPC News - O grach MMORPG słów kilka!</a>
    </div>
    <div clas="container-fluid row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 section-bluer">
        <div class="bluer">
          Projekty Firaszka
        </div>
        <div class="row section-first">
          <div class="col-sm-1 section-picture">
            <img src="fb.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8 section-this">
            asdasdas
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 section-last-post">
            asdasd
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see

[image]

This is the problem.

Row in row and `row section-first"` goes a little bit beyong previous row

Tried many things but completly no Idea how to fix it.

It's problem with the width of this rows that doesn't fit previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap class **.row** has **margin-left & margin-right** of **-15px**.

You need to compensate this by removing margin-left & margin-right. Like this:

```
.section-first {
    margin: 0;
}
```

or

```
.section-first {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Totally missed this margin, chrome didn't show me this one mehh

Answer (score 1):

Plz correct your bootstrap html structure like :

container > row > col-*-*

or

container-fluid > row-fluid > col-*-*

you put "row" with "container" its not correct format you must create like given structure :-

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-5"></div>       
   </div>  
</div>
```

your html code is here 
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/inewton/pen/eRxrOe)

Answer (score 0):

Set `.section-first` margin to 0......simple :)

```
.section-first {
    margin: 0;
}
```